pasting together more variable using mutate whithout hard-coding for column name R
I have already checked previous similar posts but I did not find the solution I need.
I needed to paste more variable together in a new column using mutate and paste but I need to avoid hard-coding for the column name.
Here is an example dataset:
test <-data.frame(name=c("Andrea","Matteo","Matteo","sonia" ),  code=c("A", "A", "B", "B"),number=c(1,1,2,2),
                  surname=c("surname1", "surname2", "surname3","surname4"))

and I need the equivalent of this:
test1 <- test %>%
  mutate(aggregate=paste(surname, number, name))

without harcoding for the column name.
I tried:
needed1 <-"name"
test2 <- test %>%
  mutate(aggregate=paste(surname, number, paste(needed1)))

but it does work as expected.
What could be the solution?
Thanks!

Is needed1 always length 1?

@lotus agreed - it's a common one.  Is there a main example to link back to for consistency (one particularly well-answered or well maintained response for example)?

@PGSA - already closed. looking for some better dupes to add.

One option would be to use tidyr::unite and tidyselect::all_of like so:
needed1 <-"name"

library(tidyr)

test |> 
  unite(
    "aggregate", 
    surname, number, all_of(needed1),
    remove = FALSE,
    sep = " "
  )
#>           aggregate   name code number  surname
#> 1 surname1 1 Andrea Andrea    A      1 surname1
#> 2 surname2 1 Matteo Matteo    A      1 surname2
#> 3 surname3 2 Matteo Matteo    B      2 surname3
#> 4  surname4 2 sonia  sonia    B      2 surname4


test2 <- test %>%
  mutate(aggregate = paste(surname, number, get(needed1)))

gives
all.equal(test1, test2)

